# When using Flask, why do you use the url_for() method for serving static files? Why can't you just use the relative path?

Tags: flask

I'm taking a Udemy course for python that includes web development and I'm creating a blog website. One of the tasks for the lesson is to create separate htmls for the header and footer to make use of Jinja Templating. Another task under the same assignment requires that I build a dynamic url for the static resources instead of just pointing at the static folder. Why is this necessary or desirable? What happens if I just point to the static folder?

TLDR: Why (1) over (2) below?

```
(1) <script src="{{ url_for('static', filename='js/scripts.js') }}"></script>

(2) <script src="js/scripts.js"></script>
```

Comment: It's useful in case you want to move that directory, you'd just change the directory's location in your configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Basically the upside of using `url_for` is that if you change one thing, everything else doesn't have to change. Say I have the `api` blueprint. If I decide to upgrade to a v2 api, then I can just leave the `url_for`s alone and have outside clients use `/api/v2/`, making it much simpler for you so you don't have to refactor all of your code. (If you use service workers it's even worse since they cache stuff.) Obviously, you don't have to do this for static files if you don't plan to change the directory, but it has its uses.